# Taking Mean for several elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

i have the following question: Let us assume we have the following list:

```
list={1.1,1.2,1.0,2.1,2.2,2,0,3.1,3.0,3.2}
```

I need a function that always takes three values of this list and put the Mean of these three values into a new list so I want to end with:

```
list2={1.1,2.1,3.1}
```

How can i do this easily?

Thank you in advance

Edit: Thank you very much

Comment: If you've received a satisfactory answer to your question, you don't have to edit your post to say thank you, you should [accept the answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) instead.

Comment: And you should upvote any answer you like, too.

Comment: I changed the marked duplicate to one that truly is a duplicate.  Please also see the questions linked in my answer there.

Answer (score 3):

```
Mean/@Partition[list,3]
```

This partitions the list into a list of lists with three elements each, and then finds the mean of each list and stores the results in a list. This will only work for lists of length 3, 6, etc.

In the example you've given, there's a stray $0$ which I think you may have missed.